# How to present a view controller from another view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am trying to open a ViewController from within another ViewController if certain conditions are met. The code seems to run without error but the view is never shown.  I am new to xcode 4 /ios 5 so I must be missing something.

Here is the code responsible for opening the second viewcontroller:

```
CreateUserViewController *createUserController = [[CreateUserViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CreateUserView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle] keyWrapper:keyChainWrapper];

    [self presentViewController:createUserController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In my project I have a xib called, "CreateUserView". I have added a view controller to this xib and assigned it to, "CreateUserViewController".

Also I noticed in the apple documentation that is shows setting the delegate of the viewcontroller to be presented. But it seems that no property called, "delegate" is on the viewcontroller object. Is this documentation old? This is the document I am trying to use (section 9-1):

[View Controller Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW1)

Can someone give me a hint? Thanks..

**edit** Adding Custom Constructor

```
    -(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil keyWrapper:(KeychainItemWrapper *)keyWrapper
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if(self){
        [self setKeyChainWrapper:keyWrapper];
    } 
             return self;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your custom `-initWithNibName:bundle:keyWrapper:` method on `CreateUserView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS5 the method for pushing new view controllers was really changed around quite a bit from iOS4 and Xcode 3.  In summary, storyboards are now used to create your application view controller flow.  Even though you may use standalone .xib files to build an application it is much less common in iOS5.

Anyway, the main method for pushing new view controllers onto the screen is done using segues.  Check out this tutorial for an introduction: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

It does a good job on explaining how to create a storyboard and use segues.  You can still present view controllers in code "the old way" but it is much much less common now with the introduction of these new technologies.  There are also some absolutely awesome tutorials on iTunes U - search for CS193P.  It's the Stanford Introductory class to Objective-C and programming for iOS.  This should get you started and maybe help you think of a way to push your `createUserController` in a way more up to speed with iOS5.

**UPDATE**

I just wanted to add. If you configure your program to use storyboards and segues you can use the method `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` to perform the segue to your `createUserController` view if the proper conditions are met.  See the Apple API for UIViewController for information on how to use this method.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have done some work with Storyboards and Seques. The problem I am trying to solve is when a view is displayed dynamically. Meaning.. I only show this dialog if a user is not currently logged in.It didn't look this was a use case for segues (but Im very new to them). Ill look into performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: Thanks!

Comment: Nick - in order to display the VC dynamically you can define the segue in the storyboard and then in some appropriate place in your code do your checking to see if you need to show the VC or not.  If you do just use that performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: method.  Good luck!

Comment: @JakeV what if we are not using storyboard in iOS5, and we need to present programmatically? is [self presentModalViewController:x animated:YES]; depreciated?

Comment: @Dpk As per the UIViewController docs you'll want to use one of the methods listed under "Presenting Another View Controller’s Content" to present a view controller programmatically when not using storyboards. I'd start with `presentViewController:animated:completion:` and `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` unless you really mean to present a view controller modally.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding `CreateUserView.xib`: you don't want to put a `CreateUserViewController` object in the nib.  You want to set the custom class of the File's Owner placeholder to `CreateUserViewController`.  Then you need to connect the `view` outlet of File's Owner to the top-level view in the nib.

Regarding the `delegate` property: The `UIViewController` class doesn't have its own `delegate` property.  The idea is that you add a `delegate` property to your subclass of `UIViewController`.  The delegate provides a way for your presented view controller to pass custom information back to the presenting view controller.

Why would you want to do that?  Let's consider the code you posted.  I'll assume you have a `UserListViewController` that shows a list of User objects, and has a "Create new user" button.  When the user touches the "Create new user" button, you create a `CreateUserViewController` and present it.

The user interacts with the `CreateUserViewController` to set the attributes of the new User object - name, rank, hairstyle, etc.  Then he touches a "Done" button.  Your `CreateUserViewController` creates the new User object and puts it in the database.  Then it needs to dismiss itself, so the `UserListViewController`'s list of User objects will appear again.

But you want the User list to include the newly created User object and you want to scroll the list so that the new User is on the screen.  So you need a way to have your `CreateUserViewController` tell the `UserListViewController` about the newly created User object.  This is where the delegate comes in.

You define a protocol like this:

```
@protocol CreateUserViewControllerDelegate

- (void)didCreateUser:(User *)user;

@end
```

and you give your `CreateUserViewController` a `delegate` property:

```
@interface CreateUserViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<CreateUserViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

// ...
```

When your `CreateUserViewController`'s "Done" button is touched, you notify your delegate of the new User:

```
- (IBAction)doneButtonWasTouched:(id)sender {
    User *user = [self createUser];
    [self.delegate didCreateUser:user];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

In your `UserListViewController`, you adopt and implement the protocol:

```
@interface UserListViewController <CreateUserViewControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

// ...

@end

@implementation UserListViewController

- (void)didCreateUser:(User *)user {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.users count] inSection:0];
    [self.users addObject:user];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
}
```

and when you need to present a `CreateUserViewController`, you set the new controller's delegate to the `UserListViewController`:

```
- (IBAction)createUserButtonWasTouched:(id)sender {
    CreateUserViewController *createUserController = [[CreateUserViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CreateUserView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle] keyWrapper:keyChainWrapper];
    createUserController.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:createUserController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: I'm going to give this a try asap. Thanks for this!

Comment: this is a really good answer. I appreciate the delegate example. However.. I still cannot get my view opened from the other viewcontroller. I removed the viewcontroller from the xib as you suggested. I assigned the CreateUserViewController to the File Owener place holder. I then assigned the view on the view controller  to the view on the xib.